# Why Angular.io styles are defined outside of the components?

Tags: angular

I don't know where to ask for this kind of questions... but...

When looking inside the new [angular.io](https://angular.io/) source code, I found that all the styles are declared in separated [scss files](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio/src/styles) outside of the components, and then referenced in a [`main.scss`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/src/styles/main.scss) file at the root of the application.

Why don't they use the `styles` attribute in the component declaration ? Is it the new best practice for styling Angular application ?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: I assume that is done to avoid css encapsulation altogether. I wouldn't say it is the best practice. It depends on the needs of your application